# Programmatically generated dynamic link not working?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to generate forgot password dynamic link using flutter (dart),
the following code is the function that I'm using

I am using `firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.1` package

```
void forg(context) async {
        if(User['Email'] != '' && User['Email'] != null) {
            Firestore.instance.collection('customer').where('Email', isEqualTo: User['Email']).getDocuments().then((onValue) {
                if(onValue.documents.length != 0) {
                    onValue.documents.forEach((doc) async {
                        DynamicLinkParameters parameters = new DynamicLinkParameters(
                            uriPrefix: 'https://<sudomain>.page.link/forgotPass' + doc.documentID,
                            link: Uri.parse('https://grihasti.com/forgot/' + doc.documentID),
                            androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
                                packageName: 'com.xyz.wxyz',
                                minimumVersion: 1
                            ),
                            iosParameters: IosParameters(
                                bundleId: 'com.xy.wxyz',
                                minimumVersion: '1.0.0',
                                appStoreId: '962194608'
                            ),
                            socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
                                title: 'Grihasti app reset password',
                                description: 'Click on the link to reset password for tour account with ' + doc.data['Name'].toString()
                            )
                        );
                        final Uri forgetLink = await parameters.buildUrl();
                        await launch(forgetLink.toString());
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        content: Container(
                            height: 15,
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                    .spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                        'User not found'
                                    ),
                                    FlatButton(
                                        child: Text(
                                            'Register'
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () =>
                                            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                                '/register',
                                                arguments: RegS(
                                                    pass, User['Email'])
                                            ),
                                    )
                                ],
                            ),
                        ),
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                    ));
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Container(
                    height: 15,
                    child: Text(
                        'Enter email',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            ));
        }
    }
```

but I get a clean build and everything when using a browser to access the link I get this
[Even though I have my URL whitelist setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5mMm.png)

the link does not appear on my firebase console, also if I make a link over there and try to use it, it's working fine